# How to install rmagick on windows 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rmagick

I am trying to install a gem which has rmagick as a dependency on windows 10. But each time I try to install it, this error appears:

```
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20160126-6648-ks1v6.rb extconf.rb --  with-opt-dir=C:/ImageMagick
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
extconf.rb:110:in ``': No such file or directory - identify -version    (Errno::ENOENT)
    from extconf.rb:110:in `configure_compile_options'
    from extconf.rb:16:in `initialize'
    from extconf.rb:517:in `new'
    from extconf.rb:517:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby22-   x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rmagick-2.15.4 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x64- mingw32/2.2.0/rmagick-2.15.4/gem_make.out
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions with: '--with-opt-dir=C:/ImageMagick'
This could take a while...
```

I have even installed the gem imagemagick, but it doesn't allow me to install rmagick. How are you supposed to install rmagick on windows 10?

Comment: One thing to remember is to close and restart the CommandPrompt after installing ImageMagick. Only then the option "add application to system path" will take effect.

Comment: Late at the party. Check out this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39513938/1903781) on how to install `rmagik` on windows 10.

Answer (score 5):

You have to use the correct version of ImageMagick, and have to reference that when you install the gem:

- [Download ImageMagick 6.9.x HDRI Q16 (64bit)](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php) ([direct](http://www.imagemagick.org/download/binaries/ImageMagick-6.9.3-2-Q16-HDRI-x64-dll.exe))
- Install it into a path **without spaces**
- Reference the installed files when you install the gem:

Here is the gem:

```
gem install rmagick --platform=ruby -- '--with-opt-dir="[path to ImageMagick]"'
```

---

## Update

Here's a [good reference](https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_install_rmagick_gem_on_Windows)

Here's how to install it step-by-step:

1. **[Download](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php) & Install ImageMagick**

[image]

There used to be a problem with newer versions of RMagick; we installed the version `6.9.2`, which is working on Win10 x64:

[image]

You need to make sure you have the above two checkboxes ticked (`C headers` && `system PATH`). The headers are used by the gem to compile (the likely reason for your error); `PATH` is used to call ImageMagick from the cmd.

You also need to make sure...

- Install path has **no spaces**
- You download [`dll` version of ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/download/binaries/ImageMagick-6.9.3-2-Q16-HDRI-x64-dll.exe) (contains C Headers)
- We got the HDRI version; it doesn't really matter

--

2. **Install the gem**

Like `mysql2` etc, you need to make sure you reference the installed libraries in order to get `rmagick` to install:

```
gem install rmagick --platform=ruby -- --with-opt-lib="c:/path_to_image_magick/lib" --with-opt-include="c:/path_to_image_magick/include"
```

This may take a while, but should install.

Comment: I've tried that countless times, but DevKit keeps preventing the gem from being installed, and the command line stated that DevKit is needed to install the gem.

Comment: There is a trick to doing it. Admittedly, I've forgotten the specifics, we have it running.

Comment: Yes, and there are not any answers on how to install it online.

Comment: Want to go to chat about it? I remember having to fiddle with it to get it to work

Comment: Ok, where can we chat?

Comment: Can someone please show me on this interface of Stack Overflow how to install imagemagick properly with DevKit to install rmagick?

Comment: Update written; if you want to go to chat, I'll help you install it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101865/discussion-between-rich-peck-and-metaco57).

Comment: Sorry, I don't have enough reputation points to go into chat on here.

Comment: I have wasted 4 hours researching on this. Got it installed last year but this time I had no luck. Thanks to your links I finally got it working.It seems this issue is caused of incompatible Imagemagick and Rmagick versions. I got it working with Imagemagick 6.9.3-2-Q16-HDRI-x64-dll, and rmagick-4.1.2.

Comment: The current link to imagemagick 6.9 is https://legacy.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use the 32-bit (i.e. x86) versions of ruby AND devkit. For some reason the build process for rmagick crashes with the 64-bit versions.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling with this problem in 2021, I just installed the latest version of rmagick on Windows, using `ImageMagick-6.9.12-33-Q16-HDRI-x64-dll`

https://download.imagemagick.org/ImageMagick/download/binaries/

Steps:

Clean up your env variables (PATH) from any previous ImageMagick installation. This is important because the gem will look into each defined path for headers,  previous configuration can pollute the installation (it happened to me). Uninstall everything.

1. Run the installer, include C headers with the checkbox.
2. Run `gem install rmagick --platform=ruby -- '--with-opt-dir="C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.12-Q16-HDRI"'`. Change the folder to your own.
3. Make sure this folder has been added to your `PATH`
4. To verify the installation, run `convert`. It should call the convert function.

For those wanting to install `rmagick` in a rails application instead, follow the same steps for ImageMagick, but manually add the PATH. This should be working.