# ERROR: Error installing rmagick: in Windows with Ruby 2.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rmagick

I cloned my code from git to my Windows machine and when I run bundle install, I am getting this error:

> An error occurred while installing rmagick (2.13.4), and Bundler
>   cannot continue. Make sure that `gem install rmagick -v '2.13.4'`
>   succeeds before bundling.

```
D:\project\MyProject2>gem install rmagick -v '2.13.4'
```

> Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit... Building native
>   extensions.  This could take a while... ERROR:  Error installing
>   rmagick:
>           ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> ```
> D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20160721-7208-bn9t3e.rb extconf.rb checking for Ruby version
> ```
>
> > = 1.8.5... yes Invalid drive specification. Unable to get ImageMagick version
> >     *** extconf.rb failed *** Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check
> >     the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration
> >     options.

I tried downloading ImageMagick, and set environment paths as:

```
CPATH=D:\ImageMagick-6.9.5-Q8\include
LIBRARY_PATH=D:\ImageMagick-6.9.5-Q8\lib
```

and run bundle install but no use and also tried running

```
gem install rmagick  -v '2.13.4' --platform=ruby -- --with-opt-lib=D:\ImageMagick-6.9.5-Q8\lib --with-opt-include=D:\ImageMagick-6.9.5-Q8\include
```

it is showing:

> Unable to get ImageMagick version
>   *** extconf.rb failed *** Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check
>   the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration
>   options.

Please help.

Comment: Have you found an answer? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue myself until I finally stumbled upon the answer on Stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36664811/1903781) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12435324/1903781).

Basically you need to follow these steps:

- Install [DevKit](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit). Since I used RailsInstaller to install Ruby on Rails on my laptop, it was already included in the default directory ‘C:\Serever\RailsInstaller\DevKit‘. Otherwise, find the .exe at the [RubyInstallers downloads](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/).
- Install `ImageMagick-6.9.5-9-Q16-x86-dll.exe` from [imagemagick.org](http://www.imagemagick.org/download/binaries/). It seems that `rmagik`2.16 only supports ImageMagick 6, not ImageMagick 7.
- Make sure that you install the correct version of ImageMagick x86 or x32. If you are unsure what ruby version you have install try this command: `ruby -e "puts 1.size"`. It print 4 if x86 and 8 if x64. answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32992267/1903781)
- Check the following options on the install screen (more info on the [redmine website](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_install_rmagick_gem_on_Windows)) :

  - [v] Add application directory to your system path
  - [v] Install development headers and libraries for C and C++
- Setup in windows environment variables the `PATH` variable to include the path to ImageMagick. In my case: `C:\Server\ImageMagick\`. Make sure it is the first variable in the variables list, or you may encounter an “Invalid drive specification” error when extconf.rb tries to identify the ImageMagick version.
- `cd C:\YourRubyProject`. Example: `C:\Server\htdocs\dev-ruby\redmine`.
- Set `CPATH` and `LIBRARY_PATH` environment variables to point respectively to ImageMagick installation directory include and lib subdirectories (so the DevKit will find them at build time)
- Open `C:\Serever\RailsInstaller\DevKit\msys.bat`. More details [here](http://codeofalice.com/code/installing-rmagick-on-windows-7/)
- Run `gem install rmagick --platform=ruby -- --with-opt-lib=C:/Server/ImageMagick/lib --with-opt-include=C:/Server/ImageMagick/include`. Adjust paths as necessary for your project.
- Finally, run `bundle install`, or if necessary `bundle update`

Note: for those that are looking to install redmine in xampp follow this [tutorial](http://nlb-creations.com/2013/06/26/installing-ruby-on-rails-and-redmine-with-xampp-on-windows-7/). If you get stuck on installing the `rmagick` lib, return here to this answer and follow the provided steps.